# short-circuit evaluation also does evaluate the right hand operand even if it determines the result from the left one?

Tags: c++11

based on short-circuit evaluation rules the right hand operand is evaluated only if the left hand operand does not determine the result. 
so why

```
void inverse(string& s)
{
    string::iterator first = s.begin();
    string::iterator last = s.end();
    while (first!= last && first!=--last)
    {
        swap(first, last);
        ++first;

    }
}
```

seems to evaluate the right one even if the left condition is true?

and this is my swap function :

```
void swap(string::iterator beg, string::iterator end)
{
    std::cout << *end << std::endl; //to test if end points to the last element or one past the last element
    char temp = *beg;
    *beg = *end;
    *end = temp;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the right-hand operand is being evaluated?

Comment: because the swap function call passes decremented last to its second parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why seems to evaluate the right one even if the left condition is true?

Because `&&` is *`and`* operator – it returns true when *both* operands are true.

Only left operand being true is not enough to turn whole expression true.
If you want that, use *`or`* operator (`||`) instead.

However, when left operand is false, no matter what the right operand is,
whole expression can't be true. Then, right operand is not evaluated.